# How to enable shmop in WHM?

Tags: php, apache, shared-memory, whm

I need to enable **shmop PHP module** to implement a shared memory system.

However, **WHM** doesn't provide shmop in the exhaustive list of modules through **EasyApache**.

How to enable shmop in WHM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use shmop compile PHP with the `--enable-shmop` parameter in the configure line.

First create a custom configure flag for this PHP extension:

```
/var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/all_php5
```

Or edit the following one if you get a file already exists message:

```
/var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/.all_php5.swp
```

and add the following line:

```
--enable-shmop
```

then run EasyApache to complete the installation

**Ressources**

- [EasyApache: Raw Opts (Custom Configure Flags)](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache/EasyApacheRawOpts)
- [Thread: Installing Shmem](https://forums.cpanel.net/cpanel-whm-discussions/319442-installing-shmem-post1307871.html)
- [How to Create and Edit Text File in Linux by Using Terminal](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-and-Edit-Text-File-in-Linux-by-Using-Terminal)